# How do I identify what value is cauasing a "Cannot add or update a child row" in my update statement?

Tags: mysql, sql-update, foreign-keys, children

I'm using MySql 5.5.37.  I have a table with a varchar(32) id

```
mysql> desc grade;
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field       | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| ID          | varchar(32) | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| NAME        | varchar(20) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| GRADE_ORDER | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

I'm trying to update a column that links to the above ID column, but I get an error complaining about failing to find a matching value ...

```
mysql> update resource r set grade_id = convert(substring_index(substring_index(r.description, 'Grade ', -1), ' ', 1), unsigned integer) where r.description like '% Grade%';
ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`my_db`.`resource`, CONSTRAINT `FK3_RESOURCE` FOREIGN KEY (`GRADE_ID`) REFERENCES `grade` (`ID`))
```

How do I identify what the offneding value is?  I notice that the number of resources I have matches the number of cross joins I'm able to make between my two tables ...

```
mysql> select count(*) FROM (select convert(substring_index(substring_index(r.description, 'Grade ', -1), ' ', 1), unsigned integer) from resource r where r.description like '% Grade%') q;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|     1340 |
+----------+
1 row in set, 7 warnings (0.01 sec)

mysql> select count(*) from resource r, grade g where convert(substring_index(substring_index(r.description, 'Grade ', -1), ' ', 1), unsigned integer) = g.id and r.description like '% Grade%'  ;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|     1340 |
+----------+
1 row in set, 1431 warnings (0.02 sec)
```

So if everything is matching up, how do I figure out what is failing to update?

**Edit:** All primary keys for all tables are of type VARCHAR(32)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a SELECT statement, return the expression that returns the "new value" for `grade_id`.

```
 SELECT r.description
      , SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(r.description, 'Grade ',-1),' ',1) AS foo 
   FROM resource r
  WHERE r.description like '% Grade%'
```

To test which of the new `grade_id` values don't match an `id` in `grade`, we can use an *anti-join* pattern. That's an outer join to return the rows from `resource`, along with matching rows from grade, and then exclude all rows that had a match. Leaving rows from `resource` where there wasn't a matching row in `grade`.

```
 SELECT r.description
      , SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(r.description, 'Grade ',-1),' ',1) AS foo 
      , CONVERT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(r.description, 'Grade ',-1),' ',1),UNSIGNED) AS fu
   FROM resource r
     -- anti-join exclude matching rows
   LEFT
   JOIN grade g
     ON g.id = CONVERT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(r.description, 'Grade ',-1),' ',1),UNSIGNED)
  WHERE g.id IS NULL
    AND r.description like '% Grade%'
```

The equality comparison on `g.id` guarantees us that expression will not be NULL for matching rows. If we exclude all non-NULL values of g.id, that excludes all rows that had a match.

---

The most likely explanation is unanticipated data in the description column, or possibly the unanticipated behavior of the `SUBSTRING_INDEX` function when a match isn't found.

**FOLLOWUP**

If that query is executing successfully and returning zero rows, then every new `grade_id` value is a match to an `id` in `grade`.

So the puzzle is why an UPDATE statement is throwing a foreign key constraint violation.

We need to rule out a `BEFORE UPDATE ON resource` trigger that's mucking with `grade_id`. Once we rule that out...

Maybe it's the implicit datatype conversion that is causing the issue.  Let's cast that integer value into a character string before we do the comparison. The same query as above, but with a `CONVERT( expr ,CHAR(32))` wrapper.

```
 SELECT r.description
      , SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(r.description, 'Grade ',-1),' ',1) AS foo 
      , CONVERT(
          CONVERT(
            SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(r.description, 'Grade ',-1),' ',1)
          ,UNSIGNED)
        ,CHAR(32)) AS new_grade_id
   FROM resource r
     -- anti-join exclude matching rows
   LEFT
   JOIN grade g
     ON g.id
      = CONVERT(
          CONVERT(
            SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(r.description, 'Grade ',-1),' ',1)
          ,UNSIGNED)
        ,CHAR(32))
  WHERE g.id IS NULL
    AND r.description like '% Grade%'
```

If that's still returning zero rows, then we might suspect an order of operations issue. Like the new `grade_id` value to be assigned is being checked *before* the `WHERE` clause is applied. But that doesn't make sense. (I'd be very surprised if that was the case.)

As a test, I'd write a query that returns the old `grade_id` value and the new value to be assigned to `grade_id` column. Assuming that `resource` has an `id` column as PRIMARY KEY:

```
 SELECT r.id
      , r.description
      , r.grade_id   AS old_grade_id
      , CONVERT(
          CONVERT(
            SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(r.description, 'Grade ',-1),' ',1)
          ,UNSIGNED)
        ,CHAR(32))   AS new_grade_id
   FROM resource r
  WHERE r.description like '% Grade%'
```

If that query is returning the results we expect, we can reference that as an inline view in a multi-table update statement, with a join on the `id` column.

Something like this:

```
 UPDATE resource t
   JOIN ( SELECT r.id
               , r.description
               , r.grade_id   AS old_grade_id
              , CONVERT(
                  CONVERT(
                    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(r.description, 'Grade ',-1),' ',1)
                  ,UNSIGNED)
                ,CHAR(32))   AS new_grade_id
           FROM resource r
          WHERE r.description like '% Grade%'
        ) v
     ON v.id = t.id
    SET t.grade_id = v.new_grade_id
```

Comment: When I ran second query from your answer, the "anti-join" query, I got no results.  I thought the second query was supposed to tell me what rows weren't matching and as such, were causing the foreign key errors?

Comment: If that query runs successfully but returns no rows, then all of the new `grade_id` values match an `id` in `grade`. As far as why the `UPDATE` statement is throwing a foreign key constraint violation, that seems bizarre. We might tend to suspect an issue with order of operations, the  new value for `grade_id` being checked BEFORE the WHERE clause is evaluated, but that is totally unexpected, I'd be really surprised if that were the issue. I suggest testing with an UPDATE that uses an inline view.

Comment: Thanks for this elaboration.  When I ran your inline UPDATE statement, I got the erorr, "ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails ".  Regarding running the other query ("As a test, I'd write a query that returns the old grade_id" ...) what am I looking for in the results?  There are over 1,000 of them so I'm trying to figure out how to identify which row would be causing the error above.

Comment: It has be be a value of `grade_id` causing the issue. Just look at the distinct values for `new_grade_id` from the inline view query, e.g. . `SELECT DISTINCT new_grade_id FROM ( SELECT ... AS new_grade_id ... ) ORDER BY new_grade_id`. If every value returned for `new_grade_id` is a value that appears in the `id` column of the `grade` column, ruling out a BEFORE UPDATE ON resource trigger, I'm at a loss to explain the behavior, if the anti-join isn't identifying rows that don't match. Is it possible that the foreign key constraint references a `grade` table in a *different* database?

Comment: Ran the DISTINCT query as you suggested and it allowed me to track down the offending value.  Thanks for everything.

Answer (score 0):

You are converting grade_id value to unsigned integer. It should be varchar(32). Does this also fail:

```
update resource r set grade_id = convert(substring_index(substring_index(r.description, 'Grade ', -1), ' ', 1), char(32)) where r.description like '% Grade%';
```

Your test queries work because of automatic type conversion. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/type-conversion.html

Comment: Yeah I'm doing that because if I don't convert it to an integer, I'll be left with grade values that are "07" that don't match anything.  If there is automatic type conversion, why isn't that kicking in during my updates?